# Webpack sass change background url to base64

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, sass

I have this Angular app, and all of my components have embedded with sass styles, I am using .NET Core Angular default boilerplate and sass-loader as my sass compiler.

- Any idea how can I change the background-url to base 64.
- Do you have any suggestion what loader to use.

For example:

```
body.login-page:not(.dashboard-pages) {
    background-image: url(/images/atc-crowd.png) <- This one to base64;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 650px;
    margin: 7% auto;

}
```

Here is my current webpack config.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const AngularCompilerPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin;
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;

function srcPath(subdir) {
    return path.join(__dirname, "ClientApp", subdir);
}

module.exports = (env) => {
    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const isDevBuild = true;
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.ts'],
            alias: {
                "@app/common": srcPath("app/common"),
                "@app/core": srcPath("app/infrastructure/core.module/providers"),
                "@app/data": srcPath("app/infrastructure/data.module/index.ts"),
                "@app/shared": srcPath("app/infrastructure/shared.module/index.ts")
            }
        },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            chunkFilename: isDevBuild ? '[name].js' : '[name].[chunkhash].js',//If production mode, add hashes to the lazy loading modules
            publicPath: 'dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: isDevBuild ?
                        ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader', 'angular2-router-loader'] : ['@ngtools/webpack', 'angular2-router-loader']

                },
                { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize'] },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000'

                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] // sass-loader not scss-loader
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
    };

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot.browser.ts' },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
                // Plugins that apply in production builds only
                new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
                new AngularCompilerPlugin({
                    tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                    entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.browser.module#AppModule'),
                    exclude: ['./**/*.server.ts']
                })
            ])
    });

    // Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        resolve: {
            mainFields: ['main'],
            alias: {
                "@app/common": srcPath("app/common"),
                "@app/core": srcPath("app/infrastructure/core.module/providers"),
                "@app/data": srcPath("app/infrastructure/data.module/index.ts"),
                "@app/shared": srcPath("app/infrastructure/shared.module/index.ts")
            }
        },
        entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot.server.ts' },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./ClientApp/dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
                sourceType: 'commonjs2',
                name: './vendor'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new AngularCompilerPlugin({
                tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.server.module#AppModule'),
                exclude: ['./**/*.browser.ts']
            })
        ]),
        output: {
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
            path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
        },
        target: 'node',
        devtool: 'inline-source-map'
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [base64-inline-loader](https://github.com/monolithed/base64-inline-loader). This should do what you want.
You can replace your image rules with this.

```
{
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
    use: 'base64-inline-loader?limit=1000&name=[name].[ext]'
}
```

But your current `url-loader` should also convert the image to base64. You have configured a limit, after which the normal `file-loader` is used. You can bump this up and see if it helps.

Comment: Tried this but does not work, because the sass is directly embedded to the component and does not produce a css file.

Comment: But your sass gets complied to css from webpack, right? If this works, the image loading should also work. I just noticed you are using an absolute path to the image, it has to be relative. Try to change that.

Answer (score 0):

In webpack v5 you should use `type`, e.g. `'asset/inline'` to get is as base64

https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/

```
{
  test: /\.(svg|png|jpg)$/,
  type: 'asset/inline' // https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found another way for me: "[postcss-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/postcss-loader/)" and "[postcss-image-inliner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-image-inliner)".

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: [/node_modules/, /dist/],
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: { outputPath: '../css/', name: '[name].css'}
      },
      {
        loader: "postcss-loader",
        options: {
          postcssOptions: {
            plugins: [
              ['postcss-image-inliner', {
                maxFileSize: 1024000,
                assetPaths: [path.resolve(__dirname + '/img')]
                }],
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      'sass-loader'
    ]
  }
```

There is an exclusion: if you write the rule

```
    background-image: url('../img/image.png');
```

- it is ok, but if you write

  ```
    background: url('../img/image.png') center center no-repeat;
  ```
- this line can be non-working. Be careful.